# Opening a workbook which its File_Name is not constant

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I’m looking for a VBA solution that will allow me to open a file, which has a variable filename.
This filename is a combination of a fixed name and a variable component. 
The fixed part of name begin with “`PM Wo  7.6`” and then the variable part and the extension of file is .`XLSB`.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.path & "\Name_of_File.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you really need. Is there **a single file** respecting the mentioned pattern? Are there **many such files**, between others and you need to open all of them, in consecutive steps and do something when they are open?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,It is only a single file with my provided pattern. I just need to open it. Anyhow, I tried the provided answer and it works as expected

Comment: Exactly! I would provide a similar answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following (untested) code will open the first file in the folder it finds that matches the file pattern:

```
Sub open_with_pattern()

    Dim fn As String
    fn = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PM Wo  7.6*.xlsb")
    
    If fn = "" Then
        MsgBox "No file found."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fn, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    '...

End Sub
```

Note: I notice in your question the filename has a double-space so I've copied that but you might need to reduce it to one if that's all the filenames have.